# why laravel Can't open connection to http://localhost:7474/db/data/?

Tags: laravel, graph, neo4j, centos, neoeloquent

I have installed neo4j as root, it runs properly and accessible for all from everywhere except for my laravel application. it gives my the error "Can't open connection to http://localhost:7474/db/data/".

Then I removed it and reinstalled it with regular user but sudoer with sudo, and again can't be accessed but the status is running.

I can not install it without sudo.

My machine is CentOS VPS on Digital Ocean. I have set up the configurations Authentication variable of neo4j to false.

If someone can help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow :) could you also post your laravel database config files?

Comment: but why do you need the config file? I think it's something related to permissions of the process or port number!

Comment: Because I am curious as to what the values for DB_PASSWORD and DB_USERNAME are in your .env file and your database.php file. Because those might cause this error (I encountered the same issue)

Comment: @SvenHakvoort, In the case of Laravel, where should those values stay ?